# webjs execution reverting when calling deployed contract: var err = new Error('Returned error: ' + message)

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

I'm running the following javascript file and using web3js to call a smart contract (0xF3885ca057a42B10b6cb432B816FE11426a2E369) on Goerli:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

// Loading the contract ABI
// (the results of a previous compilation step)
const fs = require("fs");
const { abi } = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("EtherSplitter.json"));

async function main() {
  // Configuring the connection to an Ethereum node
  const network = process.env.ETHEREUM_NETWORK;
  const web3 = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
      `https://${network}.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_PROJECT_ID}`
    )
  );
  // Creating a signing account from a private key
  const signer = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(
    process.env.SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEY
  );
  web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(signer);
  // Creating a Contract instance
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
    abi,
    // Replace this with the address of your deployed contract
    process.env.ETHERSPLITTER_CONTRACT
  );
  // Issuing a transaction that calls the splitEther method
  const tx = contract.methods.splitEther(["0xdF8b511C3682b093736318A67Fcc2FEC6772D1a6","0x1E2eBeBB3348B1FeFC29239c20Df1c78668180Cc"]);
  const receipt = await tx
    .send({
      from: signer.address,
      value: 1e15, // IS THIS CORRECT? IF NOT, HOW DO I SPECIFY VALUE FOR SEND
      gas: await tx.estimateGas(),
    })
    .once("transactionHash", (txhash) => {
      console.log(`Mining transaction ...`);
      console.log(`https://${network}.etherscan.io/tx/${txhash}`);
    });
  // The transaction is now on chain!
  console.log(`Mined in block ${receipt.blockNumber}`);
}

require("dotenv").config();
main();
```

The smart contract is:

```
contract EtherSplitter {
    function splitEther(address payable[] memory recipients) public payable {
        uint fee = 10;
        
        recipients[0].transfer(msg.value * fee / 100);
        recipients[1].transfer(msg.value * (100 - fee) / 100);
    }
        receive() external payable {
    }
}
```

Execution is reverting with the following error:

```
users/myusername/demo-eth-tx/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28
        var err = new Error('Returned error: ' + message);
```

I think I'm using send incorrectly, and incorrectly specifying the send value. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, seems like you mixed up some ether.js into your web3.js code coz in web3.js there when executing contract because in web3.js, function parameters doesn't need to be in an array like in ether.js

Try this

```js
const tx = contract.methods.splitEther("0xdF8b511C3682b093736318A67Fcc2FEC6772D1a6","0x1E2eBeBB3348B1FeFC29239c20Df1c78668180Cc");
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and got this:

Return new Error('Invalid number of parameters for "' + method + '". Got ' + got + ' expected ' + expected + '!');
               ^

Error: Invalid number of parameters for "splitEther". Got 2 expected 1!

Note that the solidity function takes in an array  - address payable[] -  which is why I was thinking to use ["",""]

Comment: Ohh gotcha so it was an array input my bad didn't notice that

hmmm let me see

Comment: Any other ideas on what I need to fix? Thanks